# Why does Thread#kill prevent new threads from being created and fail silently in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

After killing a thread, creating new threads seems to fail silently.

```
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts :ok }
sleep 2
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts :ok }
sleep 2

puts "#2"

thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts :ok }
thread.kill
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts :ok }
sleep 2
```

Output:

```
ok
ok
#2
ok
```

Last thread fails silently.

How to kill a thread and create a new one?

Tested on ruby 2.6.8p205 and ruby 3.1.0p0

Comment: "Last thread fails silently." - how did you figure that? To me, looks like the first thread is killed without having a chance to print anything.

Comment: You're  right. This example didn't capture the issue I was having...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Last thread fails silently.

You're drawing the wrong conclusion, it's the thread before that doesn't generate output. It becomes obvious if you print different values:

```
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts 'ok #1' }
sleep 2
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts 'ok #2' }
sleep 2

puts "-----"

thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts 'ok #3' }
thread.kill
thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; puts 'ok #4' }
sleep 2
```

Output:

```
ok #1
ok #2
-----
ok #4
```

> How to kill a thread and create a new one?

You exactly did that. The penultimate thread instance gets killed via `thread.kill` while it is sleeping (maybe even before). The last thread instance works as usual. There's no failure in your code.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted the question...